# Join lines between patterns

Tags: bash, join, lines

I have files with patterns delimited by `{}` with several lines, and I want to find two lines that have specific sintax on them, on my source files sometimes lines appear like this:

```
{ some text size =
          0 }
```

or

```
{ some text size
         = 0 }
```

and other cases

```
{some text size = 0 }
```

I would like to filter my source file and join those lines that match the separated condition and transform it on one line!

Comment: Tell us your thoughts on how to approach the problem.

Comment: is `tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/}/}\n/g'` sufficient?

Comment: @anishsane Most likely not, since the source files probably contain more than just those lines.

Comment: "Most likely", "probably" -> the problem is currently underspecified.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Probably. ;)

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty: (gawk needed):

```
awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub(/ size\s*=\s*0\s*}/," size = 0}")}1' file
```

test with a file with your question text as content:

```
kent$  cat test.txt
I have files with paterns delimited by {}, on my source files sometimes I have two lines like this:
{ some text size =
          0 }
or
{ some text size
         = 0 }
and other cases
{some text size = 0 }
{this should stay as it is

}

kent$  awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub(/ size\s*=\s*0\s*}/," size = 0}")}1' test.txt
I have files with paterns delimited by {}, on my source files sometimes I have two lines like this:
{ some text size = 0}
or
{ some text size = 0}
and other cases
{some text size = 0}
{this should stay as it is

}
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks for your help! Only one question more, I have found on some files my code splited on three lines ou can I verify and join those lines too. The delimiters are always { and }.

Comment: @SergioPeres did you try with my awk line with your files? it should work no matter how many lines your pattern was splitted.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solutions:

- Simple command-line:

  ```
  perl -pe 'local $/; s/({.*size *(?:= *)?)\n/$1/g;' infile >outfile
  ```
- Script:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  $filename = "/path/to/file"

  open FILE, "<$filename" or die $!;
  local $/;
  my $txt = <FILE>;
  close FILE;

  $txt =~ s/({.*size) *(?:= *\n|\n *=) *(0 *})/$1 = $2/g;

  open FILE, ">$filename" or die $!;
  print FILE $txt;
  close FILE;
  ```

Comment: it doesn't work! My file is resulted from an database export. I have a big file with several lines on it, and I would like to clean some values from some tables. I have seen and made a small script that get two lines of code that I wan't to change. The problem I have found was on some systems the file is created with splited lines.

Comment: Sounds to me like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please describe what you actually want to achieve, with a bit more context than you have provided before.